# C# Multiplication table program with loops keeps freezing up and two events not working

Tags: c#, loops

I have been working on this simple multiplication table program in C#/Visual Studio that has been giving me trouble because loops (especially do-while) are very hard for me. I was supposed to use nested for-loops and nested do-while loops and although I am not getting any errors, when I debug or run the program and click the **while-loop** button, it freezes and needs to be stopped; the **for-loop** button only shows a "0" when clicked, but the **do-while** loop button seems to work fine.

I believe these are the sections in question - for loop:

```
  for (r = 1; r < 10; r++)
        {
            for (c = 1; c < 10; c++)
            {
                intResult = r * c;
                if (intResult < 10)
                    strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                else
                    strSpace = " ";   //one space
                txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space
                txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result

                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
            }
        }
    }
```

While-loop:

```
  private void btnWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = 0; //row
        int c = 0; //column
        int intResult;
        string strSpace;

        txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
        txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

        //Outer loop goes down the rows
         r = 1; //initialize r
        do
        {

           //Inner loop goes across the columns
            c = 1; //initialize c
            do
            {


               intResult = r * c;
            } while (r < 10);

           } while (c < 10);
                strSpace = "  ";

                txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

               txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                c++;  //increment c
        {
            txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
            r++;  //increment r
        }
    }
```

Full code for reference:

```
    namespace CS10b
{
    public partial class frmCS10b : Form
    {
        public frmCS10b()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            //Outer loop goes down the rows
             r = 1; //initialize r
            do
            {

               //Inner loop goes across the columns
                c = 1; //initialize c
                do
                {


                   intResult = r * c;
                } while (r < 10);

               } while (c < 10);
                    strSpace = "  ";

                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

                   txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                    c++;  //increment c
            {
                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
                r++;  //increment r
            }
        }


        //Modify the nested while loops used above to nested do-while loops
        private void btnDoWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");

            //Outer loop goes down the rows
            //initialize r
            //do

            //Inner loop goes across the columns
            //initialize c
            //do
            for (r = 1; r < 10; r++)
            {
                for (c = 1; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    intResult = r * c;
                    if (intResult < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space
                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space
                    txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result

                    txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
                }
            }
        }


        //Modify the nested while loops used above to nested for loops
        private void btnForLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            txtTable.AppendText("\r\n"); 


            //Outer loop goes down the rows



            //for (initialize r; Boolean Condition, increment r)
             {

                //Inner loop goes across the columns
                //for (initialize c; Boolean Condition, increment c)
                {
                    intResult = r * c;

                    if (intResult < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space
                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

                    txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                }

                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
            }
        }


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


}
}//end of form

//end of namespace
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do while is infinite loop because of mistakes in braces

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary : So that will fix both issues, and how exactly do I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: The code that has the comment `//wait one second to see the clear text box` won't work - the `Thread.Sleep` freezes the UI thread that is needed to update the text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different problems, but both are caused by the same fundamental mistake: you are not letting the UI thread update while you're processing things.

As an aside: your code is very confusing. You have event handlers with names that don't really seem to match what they actually do. For example, the `do`/`while` example is in a method called `btnWhileLoop_Click()`, while the nested `for` loops example is in a method called `btnDoWhileLoop_Click()`. Then you have a method named `btnForLoop_Click()` that doesn't have any loops at all. For the purpose of this answer, I'm going to ignore the method names at least as they relate to the specific implementations, and use them only to *identify* each method.

Anyway…

In the `do`/`while` example, the main problem is that you aren't *changing* the variable that controls the loop. Since it will never change, the expression that would allow the loop to terminate never evaluates as `false` and so the loop just runs forever.

In that same method, you have a bunch of code that looks like you might have written it correctly initially, but then your little brother came along and knocked your program off the table, such that when you picked the pieces back up, you just set them back into the method in random order. I.e. it seems like all the right bits are there, but they aren't in any coherent order.

Here's a version of the method that should work better:

```
    private void btnWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = 0; //row
        int c = 0; //column
        int intResult;
        string strSpace;

        txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
        txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

        //Outer loop goes down the rows
         r = 1; //initialize r
        do
        {
            //Inner loop goes across the columns
            c = 1; //initialize c
            do
            {
                intResult = r * c;
                c++;  //increment c
                txtTable.AppendText(" "); // insert space
                txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
            } while (c < 10);

            txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
            r++;  //increment r
        } while (r < 10);
    }
```

The above still has the problem that nothing will change on the screen until the entire thing is done. But at least it is now possible for the entire thing to be done. :) I will use the nested `for` loop example to show how you can address that second problem, i.e. that nothing is shown on the screen until the entire thing is done.

There are a variety of ways to fix the problem, but IMHO the most idiomatic and natural way is to run your processing in a background task, and let the UI thread work at the same time. That might look something like this:

```
    private async void btnDoWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = 0; //row
        int c = 0; //column
        int intResult;
        string strSpace;

        txtTable.Clear();       //clear the text box
        await Task.Delay(1000); //wait one second to see the clear text box

        txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");

        // set up a helper to make it easy to update the UI from the background
        // task Non-standard event arg type of "string", because we don't need
        // anything fancier
        Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>();

        // This event is raised when progress.Report() is called (see below)
        progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            txtTable.AppendText(e);
        };

        // Wrap the loops in an anonymous method (i.e. the () => { ... } syntax)
        // and pass that to Task.Run() so it can run as a background task
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
        //Outer loop goes down the rows
        //initialize r
        //do

        //Inner loop goes across the columns
        //initialize c
        //do
        for (r = 1; r < 10; r++)
        {
            for (c = 1; c < 10; c++)
            {
                intResult = r * c;
                if (intResult < 10)
                    strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                else
                    strSpace = " ";   //one space

                // While the task is running in a thread other than your original
                // UI thread, using the "progress" object here allows the task to pass
                // data back to the UI thread where it is allowed to call e.g.
                // txtTable.AppendText() to update the UI.
                progress.Report(strSpace); // insert space
                progress.Report(intResult.ToString());  //insert result

            }

            // I think you wanted this line outside the inner loop
            progress.Report("\r\n");  //Move down one line
        }
        });

        // There's nothing else to do. But if you wanted to you could add code here
        // to do something after the task is run. Using "await" allows the UI thread
        // to keep running while the task is running, and then return control to
        // this method here when it's done.
    }
```

**Notes:**

- You may be unfamiliar with the task, threading, progress, async, etc. stuff in the second example. Unfortunately, while you are really just trying to learn about loops, you have chosen to implement your code in a GUI API (i.e. Winforms). Such APIs generally have important and strict rules about how the UI is updated, and for the type of code you're writing, the best way to comply with those rules is to write the code as above. IMHO it would have been better and easier for you had you implemented your looping examples in a console program, where output is immediate. I hope that the above does not disorient you too much.
- The `async` keyword is used to mark a method in which the `await` keyword is used. You can read details about how to use these elsewhere; the short version is that using `await` allows the method to actually return to the caller *temporarily* so that the thread that called the method can keep running while the method itself is waiting on something to happen. When that something happens, the method will resume executing after the `await` statement or expression. This is a key technique for allowing the UI thread to continue to work while some other task is running in a different thread.
- In most GUI APIs, including Winforms, WPF, Winrt, Java, and others, there is a single "UI thread" where UI objects must be accessed. If you write code that executes in some other thread, and that code needs to somehow interact with or update the UI, there are API-specific techniques for accomplishing that. In .NET, one of the simplest mechanisms for doing this is to use the `Progress<T>` class. This class hides all of the gory details required (see e.g. the `Control.Invoke()` method), and makes it easy to pass data back to the UI thread in straightforward way.
- The net effect of all of the above is that the UI thread is not blocked while you are running your loops. Instead, they get to run in a different thread. That way, when they do access the UI (via the `progress` object), the UI can respond to your updates by redrawing itself and showing the new data on the screen while the task is still running.
- All of this will happen very quickly. You might want to throw a `Thread.Sleep(100)` statement into the inner loop so that you can see things happen as they actually proceed. With only 100 iterations, it's entirely possible that without that, even with the UI thread unblocked it *still* won't update until the processing is over.
- You can apply the exact same technique as in the second example to your first example (the `do`/`while` example) so that it too can update the UI while your loops are actually running.